# Online judgeProblem (Wrong Answer)

Tags: c

problem in Light OJ:
1001 - Opposite Task:

This problem gives you a flavor the concept of special judge. That means the judge is smart enough to verify your code even though it may print different results. In this problem you are asked to find the opposite task of the previous problem.

To be specific, I have two computers where I stored my problems. Now I know the total number of problems is n. And there are no duplicate problems and there can be at most 10 problems in each computer. You have to find the number of problems in each of the computers.

Since there can be multiple solutions. Any valid solution will do.

Input:
Input starts with an integer T (≤ 25), denoting the number of test cases.

Each case starts with a line containing an integer n (0 ≤ n ≤ 20) denoting the total number of problems.

Output:
For each case, print the number of problems stored in each computer in a single line. A single space should separate the non-negative integers.
Sample Input

Output for
Sample Input:

```
3
10
7
7
```

Sample output:

0(space)10

0(space)7

1(space)6

my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
 int c,sum;
 int i,j,mini=0,maxi;
 int com1,com2;

 do{
     scanf("%d",&c);
 }while (c>25);
 int t[c+1];

 for(i=1; i<=c; i++)
 {
    do{
        scanf("%d",&t[i]);
    }while (t[i]>20);
 }

 for(i=1; i<=c; i++)
 {
    maxi=t[i];
    com1=rand() % (maxi - mini + 1) + mini;
    com2=t[i]-com1;
    printf("%d %d\n",com1,com2);

 }
 return 0;
}
```

When I submit my code the judge gives wrong answer.
But while I compile the code in CodeBlocks it gives right answer.
I can't understand the problem in online judge.
How can I solve it.

Comment: Your sample inputs will not be the only inputs to be checked for, there might be several new, complicated one too

Comment: In your code,`mini` will always be zero. Why do you have such a variable? Also,try adding `srand(time(NULL));` at the start of `main` and `#include<time.h>`

Comment: Have you tried all possible inputs and all possible random numbers?

Comment: in my random number it can be zero(0) as minimum.For that i initialize mini with 0.is it making the error?

Comment: yes i tried many  @n.m

Comment: Well, so your "many" is probably somewhat less than their "many". There are 21 possible test cases. There are many many random numbers, but as you are taking `rand() % 21`, you only need to try 21 different numbers.  So you need to test just 441 combinations to have full coverage. Not an astronomical number. You can try them all by hand in an hour or so.

Comment: I did not check the logic, but array index starts from `0` in `c`. Does that make any difference?

Comment: This code never uses `t[0]`.  A little wasteful but not wrong.

Comment: Why does code check for `while (t[i]>20)` and not `while (t[i]>20 || t[i]<0)` to meet the "(0 ≤ n ≤ 20)" specification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original post has `mini=0` for all cases, but where the total problems is > 10 that may not work. I have adjusted that

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int c = 0, mini, maxi, i, com1, com2, *t;
scanf ("%d",&c);
t = malloc (c * sizeof(int));
for (i=0; i<c; i++)
    scanf ("%d", &t[i]);
printf("\n");        

for (i=0; i<c; i++) {
    if (t[i]>10) {
        maxi = 10;
        mini = t[i] - 10;
    } else {
        maxi = t[i];
        mini = 0;
    }
    com1 = rand() % (maxi - mini + 1) + mini;
    com2 = t[i] - com1;
    printf("%d %d\n",com1,com2);        
    }
free (t);
return 0;
}
```

Please note that results of `malloc()` and `scanf()` have not been checked: they should be.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looping unnecessary number of times for the input. I have removed the unnecessary loops from your code while retaining the logic you used. I made a silly mistake with my earlier answer.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
  int main()
  {
    int c = 0;
    int maxi=10;

    scanf("%d",&c);
    int t[c];

    for(int i=0; i<c; i++)
      scanf("%d",&t[i]);

    for(int i=0; i<c; i++)
    {
      int com1 = t[i],com2 = 0;
      if (t[i] > 10)
      {
         com1 = 10
         com2 = t[i]-com1;
      }
      printf("%d %d\n",com1,com2);
    }
    return 0;
  }
```