# Solving #1015 (Brush) in LightOJ

Tags: c

I am trying to solve [the following problem](http://acm.bnu.edu.cn/contest/problem_show.php?pid=12934).

#### Input

Input starts with an integer T (≤ 100), denoting the number of test cases.

Each case starts with a blank line. The next line contains an integer N (1 ≤ N ≤ 1000), means that there are N students. The next line will contain N integers separated by spaces which denote the dust unit for all students. The dust unit for any student will not contain more than two digits.

#### Output

For each case print the case number and the total required dust units.

#### Sample Input

```
+--------------+-------------------------+
| Sample Input | Output for Sample Input |
+--------------+-------------------------+
| 2            | Case 1: 16              |
|              | Case 2: 100             |
| 3            |                         |
| 1 5 10       |                         |
|              |                         |
| 2            |                         |
| 1 99         |                         |
+--------------+-------------------------+
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int kase = 0;
  int i = 0, j = 0;

  do {
    scanf("%d", &kase);
  } while (kase > 100);

  int group[kase];
  int tdust[kase];

  for (i = 1; i <= kase; i++) {
    tdust[i] = 0;

    printf("\n");
    do {
      scanf("%d", &group[i]);
    } while (group[i] < 1 || group[i] > 1000);

    int stdNumber[group[i]];

    for (j = 1; j <= group[i]; j++) {
      do {
        scanf("%d", &stdNumber[j]);
      } while (stdNumber[j] >= 100);
      tdust[i] = tdust[i] + stdNumber[j];
    }
  }
  for (i = 1; i <= kase; i++)
    printf("\nCase %d: %d", i, tdust[i]);
}
```

When I submit my code, OnlineJudge says I've got the wrong answer. How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tested your code with the sample inputs? Does it output the expected results?

Comment: Your code exhibits UB . Array indices start from 0 and end at length-1. You think that it starts from 1 and ends at length which is wrong

Comment: Find some input that results in bad output.  Run your code under a debugger.  Find out why it does not work correctly.  Fix it.

Comment: yes i tested it codeblocks and it gives ok but online judge shows problem

Comment: It looks like [you are using SO as an online debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718330/online-judgeproblem-wrong-answer), it's not. Learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting WA because your code exhibits [UB(Undefined Behaviour)](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You assume that the valid indices for an array of length `n` where `n` is a natural number, starts from 1 and ends at `n`. That is wrong.For an array of length `n`(`n` is a natural number), Array indices start from 0 and end at `n-1`.

To fix it, change

```
 for(i=1; i<=kase; i++)
```

To

```
 for(i=0; i<kase; i++)
```

And similarly,do the same for all the other loops. Also change

```
printf("\nCase %d: %d",i,tdust[i]);
```

To

```
printf("\nCase %d: %d",i+1,tdust[i]);
```

So that you get the desired result.

Comment: Did you change all the loops? If yes,try adding a `getchar()` in all the `do...while()` loops after the `scanf`